# how to get variables from servlet class to java class

Tags: java, servlets

I have servlet class  i need to get variable from that servlet class to java class 
how is

```js
<script>  
 function showCoords(event) {     
        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;
        var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;      
 }
 </script>
```

```html
 <form name="Coordinates" method="post" action="loginServlet1">
 
<input type="image"  src="graph2.jpg" onclick="showCoords(event)" height="800" width="600"></input>
<p><strong>Tip:</strong>
</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@WebServlet("/loginServlet1")
public class LoginServlet1 extends HttpServlet {

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // read form fields
    String width = request.getParameter("x");
    String heigth = request.getParameter("y");

    // System.out.println("Width: " + x);
    // System.out.println("Height: " + y);

    // do some processing here...

    // get response writer
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    // build HTML code
    String htmlRespone = "<html>";
    htmlRespone += "<h2>Your Widthis: " + width + "<br/>";
    htmlRespone += "Your Height is: " + heigth + "</h2>";
    htmlRespone += "</html>";

    // return response
    writer.println(htmlRespone);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

- in `showCoords(event)` use javascript or jquery to add the variables
  back to the form as hidden input and then use a normal HTML Submit button

or

- in `showCoords(event)` Use jquery to do a form submit with the necessary data